# how to use ng-select and ng-options

Tags: angularjs, model, angularjs-ng-options

i am loading the country list through model attiribute from the controller while arriving to this page. But the value i am selecting is not geting binded with my select. Please provide some way to work around or should i use ng-options.

```
<div class="paddingTopBtm2">
    <label class="lblAlign">Country :<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <span> <form:select name="country" path="" id="country" 
                class="searchBoxWidth" ng-model="country">
                <form:options items="${countryList}" />
        </form:select>
    </span> <br />
</div>

model.put("countryList", ctrl.getCountryList());
```

The country List is a hashmap i am putting in model and sending it to client side.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.list = [{
        id: 27,
        name: "loruth water point",
        latitude: 4.453488123,
        longitude: 35.36021409
    },
    {
        id: 28,
        name: "kibish",
        latitude: 5.286289986,
        longitude: 35.82917452
    },
}];

<select class="ui-select" data-ng-options="r.id as r.name for r in list "                                                        name="status" data-ng-model="users.status">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
</select>
```

Hope that works!!

Comment: Hi, thanks but the real problem, i am setting the model value in the client side, the data is coming in the form of hashmap from server side.

Comment: Can you post here what actually your getting in hashmap? May be that could help solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>County: </label><span><select ng-model="country" ng-options="country in countryList"/> </span>
```